# ExtJS window.setTitle chinese eastern characters

Tags: extjs, character-encoding, window, chinese-locale

I am working with ExtJS 4.0.7.  I have a window that sets the title to a user provided string.  Sometimes it will be a string of Chinese or other eastern characters.  Such characters do not display correctly in the window title.  Else where on the page they look normal.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a piece of code or create a sample e.g. on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)